# Convert list of filters Telerik?

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, telerik-mvc

How can I convert List to Ilist ?
More specifically this is the code:

```
public IList<Kendo.Mvc.IFilterDescriptor> GetFilters()
{
    List<Kendo.Mvc.FilterDescriptor> filters = new List<Kendo.Mvc.FiterDescriptor>();

    filters.Add(new Kendo.Mvc.FilterDescriptor("Column", Kendo.Mvc.FilterOperator.Contains, "1"));

    return filters;
}
```

And it give me this error: 
*"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"*

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this fairly simply with the following:

```
public IList<Kendo.Mvc.IFilterDescriptor> GetFilters()
{
    IList<Kendo.Mvc.IFilterDescriptor> filters = new List<Kendo.Mvc.IFilterDescriptor>();

    filters.Add(new Kendo.Mvc.FilterDescriptor("Column", Kendo.Mvc.FilterOperator.Contains, "1"));

    return filters;
}
```

The reason this works is because on the we create an object of type 'IList', which the rest of the code then adheres to, because it all extends those interfaces.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Actually you can't. Your code is identical with the one from my question and that code as yours throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
public IList<Kendo.Mvc.IFilterDescriptor> GetFilters()
{
    List<Kendo.Mvc.FilterDescriptor> filters = new List<Kendo.Mvc.FiterDescriptor>();

    filters.Add(new Kendo.Mvc.FilterDescriptor("Column", Kendo.Mvc.FilterOperator.Contains, "1"));

    IList<Kendo.Mvc.IFilterDescriptor>() iFilters = new List<Kendo.Mvc.IFilterDescriptor>();

    foreach(var filter in filters)
    {
       Kendo.Mvc.IFilterDescriptor temp = null;
       temp = filter;

       if(temp is Kendo.Mvc.FilterDescriptor)
       {
           iFilters.Add(temp);
       }
    }

    return filters;
}
```